# How to empty the cart automatically before adding a new item to the cart?

Tags: 6, ubercart

How to empty the cart automatically before adding a new item to the cart in [ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) ver 6?

Is it possible adding `uc_cart_empty($cart_id) ;` in uc_cart module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the cart using the following function

```
uc_cart_empty(uc_cart_get_id());
```

Use the above function in your module when you want clear cart. 
To empty the cart automatically before adding a new item to the cart call the function in hook_add_to_cart().

eg:

```
function MODULE_NAME__add_to_cart($nid, $qty, $data) {
  uc_cart_empty(uc_cart_get_id());
  drupal_set_message("Previous item cleared");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct answer:

function MODULE_NAME_uc_add_to_cart($nid, $qty, $data) {
  uc_cart_empty(uc_cart_get_id());
  drupal_set_message("Previous item cleared");
}